# Removing an item from an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, observablecollection

I have a List View which has a binding to an ObservableCollection, I am trying to have it so that when a button is pressed the item is removed from the list and the SQLite database, so far it only removes from the database, unless I restart the app then the item is no longer on in the ListView, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code Behind:

```
namespace Epicure.Views
{
public sealed partial class Ingredients : Page
{
    public Ingredients()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TestViewBinding();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Ingredient> IngredientsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>();

    public void TestViewBinding()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.path);
        var Ingredients = new  List<Ingredient>();
        Ingredients = db.Table<Ingredient>().ToList();

        foreach (var Ingredient in Ingredients)
        {
            IngredientsCollection.Add(Ingredient);
        }
    }

    private void ListUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (IngredientsCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            LonelyPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        if (IngredientsCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            LonelyPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private void RemoveClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.path);
        var Ingredients = db.Table<Ingredient>().ToList();

        foreach (var Ingredient in Ingredients)
        {
            db.Delete(Ingredient);
            IngredientsCollection.Remove(Ingredient);
        }          
    }

    private void NewIngredientClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateToPage(typeof(NewIngredient));
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Epicure.Views.Ingredients"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Epicure.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="IngredientList" ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientsCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0,1,0.5,0" BorderBrush="#FF007575" LayoutUpdated="ListUpdated">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="140" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IngredientName}"/>
                        <AppBarButton x:Name="DeleteButton" Style="{StaticResource EpicureRibbonButton}" Width="48" Click="RemoveClicked" Icon="Delete"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LonelyPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Icon" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="&#xED56;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="48" Margin="0" Foreground="#FF007575"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Foreground="#FF007575">
            <Run Text="It's lonely here,"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="want to add something?"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AddIngredient" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Label="Add Ingredient" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource AddButton}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,12,0,0" Foreground="#FF007575" Click="NewIngredientClicked">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC09;" FontSize="20"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are correctly removing the item from the collection. Can you show your XAML code as I think there's where the problem might be.

Comment: Added the list view XAML

Comment: How does that binding work ? ItemsSource={Binding Mode=TwoWay} ? Is your ViewModel your collection itself?

Comment: I honestly don't where that came from, I didn't even see it there. removed it as it didn't seem to be doing anything. the collection is in the xaml.cs file, would you like to see that too? 

as you can probably tell I'm pretty new to all this so if I misunderstand let me know.

Comment: yea. As much code as you can show will help. Ideally you want to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I see. Issue is you're not actually binding. I'll provide an answer , let me know if that works

Comment: ah okay, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think to modify observablecollection you should iterate over a copy of the collection.

Try like this where you should compare a property preferably id .

```
var copy = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>(IngredientsCollection);
copy.Remove(copy.Where(i => i.Id == Ingredient.Id).Single());
```

Comment: tried to implement this, it seems to have the same outcome

Comment: He's not iterating over the collection, he's iterating over the items he's removing so that's OK. no need to copy

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest code sample it looks like you are not actually Binding your ItemSource but rather assign it from code which will likely cause your issue.

First update your XAML to correctly bind ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection

```
<ListView x:Name="IngredientList" ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientsCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0,1,0.5,0" BorderBrush="#FF007575" LayoutUpdated="ListUpdated">
```

Remove `IngredientList.ItemsSource = IngredientsCollection;` from your `TestListViewBinding` method as this will be handled by the binding

Ensure that your View's `DataContext` is set to the class where you declare the Collection. Since it appears to be your code behind, you can just set it in the constructor

```
public Ingredients()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    IngredientsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>()
    TestViewBinding();
};
```

Make sure your `IngredientsCollection` is a property and not a field.

```
public ObservableCollection<Ingredient> IngredientsCollection { get; set; }
```

Because your Page does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the `IngredientsCollection` needs to be initialized in the constructor so that it gets bound to.

Obviously this is not the ideal way to set up you MVVM but it's a start to get you going.

Comment: the items aren't apearing in the listview anymore

Comment: There are too many pieces missing from the code. Can you share the entire XAML file and the entire code behind file?

Comment: with the changes you suggested?

Comment: ah, my bad. See update. You need to initialize the collection in the constructor or inline.

Comment: I got it to work, but I want to remove a single item not the entire list

Comment: take a look at your RemoveClick code. Looks like you're removing every item> you need to update that logic to only remove the item you clicked on

Comment: how would I go about doing this?